# Warning on startup about disk partition which has been deleted

Tags: boot, partitioning

While setting up a dual boot on my previously Ubuntu-only system I deleted one of Ubuntu's partitions, which was being mounted during boot. Now when Ubuntu starts to boot I get this message:

```
CC1E4130                # just an example - it's something like that
Is not mounted yet
S-to skip mounting
M-to manual recovery
C-to continue
```

I can choose `S` to skip, but it's annoying that I have to do this every time. How can I get rid of the message entirely?

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of this problem you can remove the line that mentions the file from `/etc/fstab`

```
cp /etc/fstab fstab.bak
sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab
```

Delete any lines mentioning deleted partition information and save the file.

At the next boot, you won't get any warnings about the missing partition.